# Can't create Azure Functions in USGovVirginia in Azure Government

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-gov

I tried to walk-through for Microsoft's [Azure Functions Quickstarts for Azure Government](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-functions) which crashes with the following error when executing `az functionapp create`:

> Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. 
>   
> Details: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: `https://management.usgovcloudapi.net/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/*<resourcegroupname>*/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<newFunctionName>?api-version=2016-08-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're investigating why USGovVirginia isn't working.

In the interim, use USGovArizona or USGovTexas.

**Update 2017-11-21**

This was a transient issue that has now been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The MSFT Team has been great in helping me through this.  J